# php/mysql: database of bank holidays and events like christmas, easter etc

Tags: php, mysql, date, time, calendar

Im working on a simple calendar application and i want to have the above events display on the calendar [bank holidays and that].

The calendar is just a standard month view, with a link to view each day for each day in the month, and links to view next/ previous month and year etc...

i will probably have the mktime for each event stored, and if today == mktime then display it on the calendar [or something similar], but where can i get these dates from?

Any suggestions ??

Comment: the calendar is functioning perfectly like, displaying whatever events the user adds, using mktime_of_event and $day_start and $day_end.
I just need a list of bank holidays like:

eventName | eventStartTime[mktime]

Easter | 1224060000 [for example]

holidays like bank-holidays can vary from year to year, like the first monday in May or easter changes each year also.

Answer (score 5):

http://pear.php.net/package/Date_Holidays has support for calculating holiday dates for a number of countries, inc UK, US, DE and others.
see [the example](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.datetime.date-holidays.example.php)