# How dynamically determining the holiday of a particular country?

Tags: javascript, php, date

I want to determine the country of holiday that you specified using the php or javascript.
Is this possible? And how?

++I want Sat,Sun and holidays for CSS automatic change. (US, UK, France, Australia, Hong-Kong, China, Germany)

```
$holiday = $t->format("D"); 
$date = $t->format("D, M j Y");

if( $holiday == 'Sun' || $holiday  == 'Sat')
{ $cal = "cal_holiday"; }
else
{   $cal = "cal";   }

echo "<a class = '$cal'><center>$date</a></center>";
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [php/mysql: database of bank holidays and events like christmas, easter etc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/947373/php-mysql-database-of-bank-holidays-and-events-like-christmas-easter-etc)

Comment: @CodingInsane OP has not any code so far its clear in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need Use third party api for this like:

1. http://www.thomson.co.uk/editorial/information/advance-passenger-information.html
2. http://www.timeanddate.com/services/api/holiday-api.html
3. http://kayaposoft.com/enrico/

Which one suit's you better, or you need to do some Research for finding Good API